# Heroku push untracked files

Tags: git, heroku, assets

I have a Python Flask app that I deploy on Heroku. It relies on generated binary data files that I have previously been generating and committing to the git repo. These files add up to about 35MB, so you can see how the repo size will eventually become unreasonable.

I definitely don't need these asset files tracked in git because they are generated, but the process is intensive enough that the Heroku app times out before it can generate them, which is why I had put them in git.

I found git-lfs and it seemed to be exactly what I needed only for me to find out Heroku doesn't support it.

How can I leave these large asset files untracked in git while still ensuring they end up in the slug for my Heroku app?

I would like to avoid the hassle of an external hosting service, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to do the following

1. Create a branch that you **never** push to your online repository. For example, I created a branch called `heroku`
2. Remove the `.gitignore` entry for the particular file/folder you want to commit to.
3. Before every push to heroku, ensure that you have built every file you need to build.
4. Push the created branch using the command `git push heroku <BRANCH>:master`. In our case, it'll be `git push heroku heroku:master`. And there you have it

One error you may face is when the branch size becomes too large. In this case, try increasing your branch size with `git config git config http.postBuffer <SIZE IN BYTES>`